# Cannot use GCloud CLI in Cloud Run

Tags: gcloud, scheduler, jobs, google-cloud-run

I would like to use GCloud CLI in my Cloud Run script. For example, to automatically create and delete jobs.

On my local pc, "gcloud scheduler jobs create ..." and "gcloud scheduler jobs delete ..." work fine. However, the same commands fail in my script. In the Cloud Run logs it says: "sh: 1: gcloud: not found".

How can I use GCloud CLI in Cloud Run?
Or is there another way to automatically create and delete jobs?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You would need to build a container that has the `gcloud` CLI. There is a Docker container that you can start with: https://hub.docker.com/r/google/cloud-sdk/

Comment: Can you share a code snippet please ?

Comment: Hi John, it's only to be sure and to see which image @Maxwell86 chose in the `From` in his Docker image. But your are right in your comment.

Comment: Can you share your script by updating your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the suggestion of John Hanley is correct and a possible way to solve my problem.

Instead I solved it by using the [CloudSchedulerClient](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/cloudscheduler/latest/google.cloud.scheduler_v1.services.cloud_scheduler.CloudSchedulerClient), rather than the GCloud CLI. As my Cloud Run script is written in Python, this is probably the easiest way.